# Angular UI-grid filter header cell style?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm working Angular UI-Grid, and exactly with filtering. All functions works fine, and now I'm working on styling.

What I'm trying to achieve is instead of this view 
[image]

I want to get this view 
[image]

So as you can see I just want to make range filter in one line. All my searches in internet have been failed. I have found some sort of info for a date picker range, but I believe it should be much simpler, just add some css rule to one columns.

I can impact on row thru `cellClass`and I have tried to impact in same way thru `headerCellClass` but it doesn't work. Is it any way to impact on this header without creating any custom templates?
Thanks in advance.

My column definition:

```
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {
            displayName: 'Name',
            field: 'name',
            width: '20%',
            cellClass: getCellClass
        },
        {
            field: 'description',
            width: '30%',
            cellClass: getCellClass
        },
        {
            field: 'strict',
            filter: {
                type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                selectOptions: [
                    {value: true, label: 'strict'},
                    {value: false, label: 'non-strict'}
                ]
            },
            cellClass: getCellClass
        },
        {
            displayName: 'Length',
            field: 'maxSize',
            filters: [
                {
                    name: 'From',
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                    placeholder: "from"
                },
                {
                    name: 'To',
                    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                    placeholder: "to"

                }
            ],
            headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader,
            cellClass: getCellClass
        },
        {
            field: 'Actions',
            cellClass: getCellClass,
            cellTemplate: "includes/grid/columnAction.html"
        }
    ];


  $scope.highlightFilteredHeader = function (row, rowRenderIndex, col, colRenderIndex) {
                return 'ui-grid-header-custom';
        };
```

this is [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/umZ3lyrImpoIp8BH7hD2?p=preview) where you can find my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found way to impact on it, I have added custom class and thru this class I can impact on inner elements. this is my working code.

```
$scope.highlightFilteredHeader = function (row, rowRenderIndex, col, colRenderIndex) {

        if (col.displayName == 'Length') {
            return 'inline-filter';
        } else if (col.filters[0].term) {
            return 'header-filtered';
        } else {
            return ''
        }
    };
```

css

```
    .inline-filter .ui-grid-filter-input-0{
    width: 40% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px !important;
}
.inline-filter .ui-grid-filter-input-1{
    width: 40% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -8px !important;
    margin-left: 5px !important;
}
.inline-filter .ui-grid-filter-container .ui-grid-filter-button {
    top: 15px !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .inline-filter .ui-grid-filter-input-0{
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```